# Entity Framework is rounding integer values or masking them

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Entity Framework change the values I pass to save to the DB (oracle).
In Oracle I have a table with a field named `PointX` as Float and Mapped to EF as Decimal.
When I run the code, the Entity to be save has a property `PointX` with value `37` and saves `40` on DB.
Examples of values I tested

Entity.`PointX` -> Oracle.`PointX`
`37` -> `40`
`6543210` -> `6000000`
`41` -> `40`
`35` -> `40`

On the block of code I paste in here, I checked the domainObject values and is always ok.
After `SaveChanges` executes I check the value in Oracle and the new value is completely wrong.

```
public virtual void Save(T domainObject)
{
    // domainObject.PointX = 37;    
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can't find why it save values this way. I'm lost.

Comment: Can we see your table definition, particularly the PointX column?

Comment: Yes... Its float an I can make updates directly to the table with toad and bring them back with EF without any problem. Only when I save the number change.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal sample that we can run?

Comment: can you intercept the sql query ?

Comment: The project is quite simple, but I tried to simplyfied the code to see that db (context) receives the object with all the properties and correct values and only on float fields I have this issue.
May be a property on mapping, or may be setting on the entity is producing this behaviour. 
Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: No I can't. I have no privileges to trace or intecept the query.
There is anyway to tell entity framework to log queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check oracle precision of float type. In my case is 126 (Oracle 10).
Edit your edmx with a text editor and check the fields of type float. If there is no precision set on the attributes, just set the same precision your found on your oracle version this way:

edmx with problem:

```
<EntityType Name="MyTableEntity">
    <...>
    <Property Name="PointX" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
```

Change the entity field setting precision:

```
<EntityType Name="MyTableEntity">
    <...>
    <Property Name="PointX" Type="float" Nullable="false" Precision="126" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. I don't understand why this attribute was not set.